# Django Allauth email templates

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-allauth, dj-rest-auth

I tried overriding the email templates but noticed that it now sends the two templates, the content of the .txt and the HTML, I followed what was specified and created the HTML versions for the signup and the confirmation. Any ideas on how to properly override the template? I wanted to use the html and not the .txt for the message but for the subject I'm fine keeping it as is.

[image]